# Update a table using temp table with select statement for multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have temp table in my SP and a table in my DB and I need to update the table in the DB, and as of now I am able to update the table using select statement.

But I am having multiple records in my temp table and I am able to update only my last row of the table in DB.

Below is the query I am having,

```
UPDATE
Table_A
SET
  Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2,
  Table_A.col3 = Table_B.col3
FROM
  Some_Table AS Table_A
  INNER JOIN temp_Table AS Table_B ON Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1
```

And DB table structures

```
col1 | col2        | col3
```

---

```
1    | India       | Delhi
2    | US          | NewYork
3    | UK          | London
```

And temp table structure as below

```
col1 | col2        | col3
```

---

```
1    | US          | NewYork
2    | UK          | London
3    | India       | Delhi
```

So, I need to update my table for multiple rows.

Comment: Why are you updating `col1` if you are joining on it? They are already equal.

Comment: Perhaps a where clause? Neither one of these tables are temp table BTW.

Comment: @SqlZim I have my updated my question, please check now

Comment: What is the issue? The code you posted would update all rows that are returned in the query but your comment says something only 1 row in the table being updated. I think that in posting your question you modified the query so much you lost the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am understanding your post I think this should be the solution for that which will update properly. Hope this helps

```
   WITH    CTE1
              AS ( SELECT   Col1 ,
                            Col2 ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COl1 ORDER BY Col2 ) AS rn
                   FROM     table_1 t1
                 ),
            CTE2
              AS ( SELECT   Col1 ,
                            Col2 ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY COl1 ORDER BY Col2 ) AS rn
                   FROM     table_2 t2
                 )
        UPDATE  br
        SET    ....
        FROM    Cte1 c1
                INNER JOIN cte2 c2 br ON c1.Col1 = c2.Col1
                                                    AND c1.rn = c2.rn;
```